# Array index property in Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java programming and I am working with arrays .In arrays 
index needs to be an integer and it doesn't allow float or double so I used long data type for index and it gave error. Whereas when I used byte and short and Int it worked . I want to know since the error was "possible lossy conversion from long to int "
Is it such that only int is allowed in index and since byte and short are small in size that's why it worked (auto promotion) and long was larger than int so it gave error(no auto depromotion)plz help

```
  import Java.util.*;
  class Demo{ 
public static void main(String args[]){
        long n=5;
        int a[]=new int[n]; //error possible lossy conversion from long to int
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }

   }
```

Comment: Yes, you're correct; only ints are usable as array indices, and `byte` and `short` can be automatically promoted to `int`.

Comment: `long` is 8 bytes, so if more than 4 bytes had information, you'd *lose* that information when converting to the 4 byte `int`. Hence `lossy conversion`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, it's because that's the way the language is designed.  If you take a look at [section 10.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7) of the Java language specifications, you'll notice that the length of the array is defined as an `int` (which is smaller than a `long`).  Semtantically, `ints` and `longs` represent integers, but "larger" integer types will not be automatically cast to "smaller" integer types.

Answer (score 0):

Needs to be int. Long, short, byte, float are ***other data types***. Implicit or explicit conversion of your supplied data type can occur, but the index of your array will only be constructed with an `int` by the javac.

An array object contains a number of variables. The number of variables may be zero, in which case the array is said to be empty. The variables contained in an array have no names; instead they are referenced by array access expressions that use non-negative integer index values. These variables are called the components of the array. If an array has n components, we say n is the length of the array; the components of the array are referenced using integer indices from 0 to n - 1, inclusive.

[Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast long to int or rather cannot convert from long to int.
The only conversion you can do is

•
byte to short, int, long, float, or double

•
short to int, long, float, or double

•
char to int, long, float, or double

•
int to long, float, or double

•
long to float or double

•
float to double

Since you have array of int you can store int ,short and byte datatype values

Comment: Can you really do `long` to `float`? I wouldn't have guessed that since `float` is 4 bytes. Learn something new everyday.

Comment: I just want to know why byte short and long are not allowed as index .When they are integers and does not include decimals.

Comment: @dcmotor You are making an ***implicit*** cast when you pass a `byte`, `short`, or `long` as the array index. The array accessor asks for an `int`, so whatever you pass it has to be convertible to `int` data type. The conversions listed above are available for *implicit* casts. You can *explicitly* cast `long` to `int`, but you could lose data. `yourArray[(int)yourLongValue]`.

Comment: I got it , so only int is allowed as index in Java and byte,short ,long are typecast into int . But  still since index needs to be a number without decimals why Java by default does not allow long,short,byte as index. Any specific reason behind  this?

Comment: @dcmotor `byte` and `short` can be cast to `int` *implicitly* because they are smaller data types, while `long` must be cast *explicitly* since it is a larger data type. It must be *explicitly* cast because the language wants you to basically confirm that you ***know*** you could lose information by casting `long` to `int`. I don't know how else to explain this. You can't fit 8 bytes (`long`) into 4 bytes (`int`) because there isn't enough room. You can fit 1 byte (`byte`) or 2 bytes (`short`) into `int` because there is enough room.

Comment: @crush I got it what u said but what I want to know is that why james gosling only allowed int as index why not long . I understand when Java does not allow float or double since size cannot be in decimals but what's the problem with long or short or byte they all are numbers without decimals

Comment: @dcmotor I can't answer that factually, but I'd venture that he decided that 2,147,483,648 indices was enough for an array. Perhaps a bit of shortsightedness, but complex data structures can bridge the gap when more indices are needed.

Comment: @crush Thanx a lot 